# Education sections in an Job Application Form

Tags: application, job-search, cv, united-kingdom

I'm trying to fill in an Application Form for a position as a Spanish Teacher in United Kingdom, and I came accross these 2 sections: ***Educational/Training and Academic qualifications*** and ***Further Education***.

[image]

What am I supposed to write in each of these sections?

Assuming I have obviously primary school and college, as well as 2 degrees and 2 postgraduate courses (all relevant for the position), where should I put each of them?

Comment: This one seems awfully confusing to me as well. They both seem to be asking for similar things in entirely different ways. I assume the first list is for anything applicable towards Spanish, such as a degree, and the second is any degrees you've obtained that are not Spanish, but I'm not from the UK, and haven't seen anything quite like it.

Comment: It seems like a way of separating education which culminates in formal degrees from any other (typically shorter) training, such as certifications or additional coursework. For Ed/Training and Acad Qual section, I would omit any school education prior to college and start with your college degree(s), starting with most recent, and include institution, dates attended, and title of degree that includes your major field (e.g. Bachelor of Arts, Spanish; Master of Arts, Education). Any additional coursework or certification would go into Further Education.

Comment: Further Education has a very specific meaning in the UK, so don't go with your intuition on this. If in doubt, I would suggest asking whoever supplied you with the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while since you asked this question so I assume it's no longer needed, but in case others come across this hoping for an answer...

In the UK, further education typically refers to any education completed after finishing GCSEs - which are typically taken at age 16 - and beginning a university degree - which typically starts at 18/19. The most common form of further education here between ages 16-18 are A levels, taken at a sixth form college or school. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Further_education

In your case, I would enter your college course in further education, and your subsequent education in the education/training and academic qualifications section.

But, ultimately, I agree - this is quite a confusing example of an application form.